# Create new dataframe from two other dataframes conditional on each row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames

```
Name1    Value
A1         1
A2         2
A3         0
A4        -3

Name2    Value
B1         1
B2        -1
B3       -10
B4         4
```

Now I want a third data frame, that picks the rows of the two data frames above, subject to a condition, in particular: "Pick the row with the smaller value"

```
Desired Output
A1         1         # <- What happens when tied?
B2        -1
B3       -10
A4        -3
```

The next question is what happens if there are ties? Actually, I would be open to take the first one for instance, or randomly picked, whatever is easier.

Comment: will you be using this on large dataframes?

Comment: yes!  right now smaller for test but the final is larger.

Comment: I don't know if I should post a second answer or something like that, I compared the computation time of each one of the 4 answers, and they scale really different, it was really interesting. For small dataframes (number of rows of around 1e3 or less) the accepted answer is the most efficient and mine the worst, whereas for large dataframes (rows > 1e4) it is the other way around. The 2 answers with `drop_duplicates` are in between.

Comment: thanks xp.plt.py, I haven't timed it, happy to change since performance is key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create the third dataframe as a copy of one of the initial ones, and afterwards substitute the values whose counterpart in the other dataframe is smaller:

```
df3 = df1.copy()
# Change this expression to choose how to treat ties
min_mask = df1.Value>df2.Value  # i.e. df1.Value>=df2.Value
df3.loc[min_mask] = df2.rename(columns={'Name2':'Name1'})[min_mask]
```

Output `df3`:

```
 Name1  Value
0   A1     1
1   B2    -1
2   B3   -10
3   A4    -3
```

There is a `rename` in `df2` in order to write the whole row to `df3`, otherwise, the columns with different name get a `NaN` value.

About the ties, you can easily choose what do you want to do by changing the greater than by greater or equal than.

## Edit:

To this date, there have been 4 answers to this question, all of them completely answer the question using different approaches, therefore, depending on their final application, this one might not be the *best* answer.

To ease the process of finding the adequate answer, I am posting a summary of the elapsed time of each of the 4 answers as a function of the number of rows in `df1` and `df2`, which usually is one of the key factors when choosing.

[image: Elapsed time comparison between methods]

Comment: Nice summary!! :)

Comment: Nice one. Not surprisingly, my solution & Wen's have similar performance. They are virtually identical. Also, there appears to be a magical point around ~1000 rows where all solutions are equally performant.

Answer (score 3):

We could recreate the dataframe by zipping together df1 and df2 values and using `min()` passing a key:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame((min(i, key = lambda x: x[1]) for i in zip(df1.values, df2.values)),
                   columns = ['Desired','Output'])
```

Returns:

```
  Desired  Output
0      A1       1
1      B2      -1
2      B3     -10
3      A4      -3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way, assuming you begin with dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
res = df1.rename(columns={'Name1': 'Name'})\
         .append(df2.rename(columns={'Name2': 'Name'}))\
         .sort_values('Value')

res = res.loc[~res.index.duplicated()]\
         .sort_index()
```

**Result**

```
  Name  Value
0   A1      1
1   B2     -1
2   B3    -10
3   A4     -3
```

**Explanation**

There are 2 steps:

1. Append `df2` to `df1` after aligning column names and sort by `Value`.
2. Drop duplicates by index, then sort by index.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={'Name2':'Name1'})]).sort_values('Value').reset_index().drop_duplicates('index').sort_values('index').set_index('index')
Out[36]: 
      Name1  Value
index             
0        A1      1
1        B2     -1
2        B3    -10
3        A4     -3
```

Comment: Thank you, Wen. I like the onliners! Just to understand, we are sorting, resetting, dropping, sorting again, reset the index; would that affect performance for larger lists (in sql sorting large lists are a performance killer)

Comment: @eternity1 nope, I think this type of function does not involved calculation should be fast :-)

Comment: I tested it, in fact it's faster, somehow I do not get the desired result. I get a result with 3 columns where the, Value, Name1 and Name2 where I have NaNs for the ones that are "losers" in the comparison.

Comment: @eternity1 you need rename df2 to df1 df2.rename(columns={'Name2':'Name1'})